# Git tool to upfront sort commits (like putting changes in buckets)

Tags: git

Let's say I work on a feature divided in three sub-features `s1`, `s2`, `s3`. On top I do some continuous formatting on my code to go into commit `f`.

I cannot do it sequentially `s1`, `s2`, `s3`, then `f`. So I usually end up with all the changes, then with `git GUI` I start to sort them. I go over the changes and pick everything for `s1`, then `s2` and so forth.

As I usually overlook something, I end up in rebasing:

`s1`, `f`, `s2`, `s3`, `f`, `s2` -> `s1`,  `s2`, `s3`, `f`

So I am looking for a way to open something like a couple of **preliminary** commits (like buckets I do sort in), where I can already sort in my daily changes:

1. Day 1 changes `s1p`, `fp`
2. Day 2 changes `s2p`, `s3p`
3. Day 3 changes `fp`, `s1p`

Now done, I want to turn the pre-sorted changes into the real commits:

`s1p`,  `s2p`, `s3p`, `fp` -> `s1`,  `s2`, `s3`, `f`

For me, this would mean a big improvement, as I could immediately sort-away my pending changes. Any chance to do so (by a tool, a git trick, ...)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no tool to do what you're asking for directly, so far as I know. However, you could make it a lot easier for yourself by prefixing all of your commit messages with whichever of the categories that commit fits into. Then when you go to do the big rebase, you can take the script from the interactive rebase list, and sort it on that category tag (using `sort` or whatever other mechanism you'd like). Then you just need to put the big batches in the right order relative to each other, and fire away.